# Clutch for high-speed operation (>40 000 rpm)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, robotics, actuator, transmission

I'm currently working on a setup where at some operations my motor has to drive a shaft up to the motor's maximum operating speed (12,000rpm) and a torque of ~0.14Nm but at other conditions this shaft can drive the motor up to 40,000 rpm. However, since this is outside the motor's operating range, and the shaft doesn't transmit any power (i.e. the torque on this shaft is zero), I want to decouple the motor from the shaft.

I have been looking for electromagnetic clutches but so fare I only found clutches with a maximum operating speed of 20,000rpm. Do you know if such clutches, of other mechanisms, exist with maximum speeds of 40,000rpm and higher?

Thank you advance!